# How to update Array in couchbase via SDK

Tags: couchbase

looked thru the docs and was wondering if there is a way to update a doc in array directly. I only found Append, Prepend and Insert and for now my work around is

```
 bucket
  .mutateIn(docID)
  .remove(path + "[" +index +"]")
  .arrayInsert(path +"[" +index +"]", doc)
  .execute((err, result) => {}
```

which works but i doubt ideal as it causes 2 operations in my case actually 3 on the doc as i have to find
the index for this Doc in array before i can delete and insert again

Answer (score 1):

There is a [sub-document](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.1/developer-guide/sub-doc-api.html#commands) command called `replace` that allows an element to be updated.

```
 bucket
  .mutateIn(docID)
  .replace(path + "[" +index +"]", doc)
  .execute((err, result) => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this method is missing in the SDK, I will open a ticket for it. In the meantime, you could also use N1QL via ARRAY_REMOVE or ARRAY_REPLACE (tks to vsr)

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-remove

Comment: If you know old doc use ARRAY_REPLACE()